# Displaying two boxes side by side as if they are one

Tags: html, css

I have this boxes http://jsfiddle.net/eqhH9/show/ and this is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eqhH9/

I want to display one box with text and the other with a glyphicon as shown in the examples.This is the `html`

```
<div class="col-sm-3 les_four">
<article class="les_two_boxes"><section class="les_b_1">hello<section class="les_b_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film "></span></section></section></article>
</div>
```

The problem is the first box `<section class="les_b_1">hello`... messes the entire box when there is more text.How can i fix this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change your html to the following for each article (`section.les_b_2` is no longer nested):

```
<section class="les_b_1">hello</section>
<section class="les_b_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film "></span></section>
```

You can use the following styles to achieve what you want:

```
.les_two_boxes {display:table; width:100%;}
.les_two_boxes > section {display:table-cell;}
.les_b_1{background-color:pink;vertical-align:top;width:60%;}
.les_b_2{border-left:1px solid white;font-size:30px;width:40%;background-color:brown;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/eqhH9/5/)

Comment: Thanks a million Pete.